# CSS - Broken active link when linked img has diplay: block

Tags: html, css

I have some divs, in there are an image and some text with link.

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" />Text</a>
</div>
```

I have CSS set for link, active, hover and visited. If I click the text, then no problem, but if I click the image the text stays on active, but if I click on the text it works again. If I remove the display: block from the img CSS, then it works, but the image is not horizontally centered in the div.

How can I solve this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthew3r/wz9pY/)

Comment: you where almost right, just move the "display: block" to an "a" style in your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
a { display:block;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wz9pY/1/)

Comment: Perfect, easier than I thought.